# Disable junit5 test when running on M1 Apple Silicon

Tags: java, kotlin, junit5, apple-m1

Is there a way to disable specific tests when they're running on M1?

I haven't found a relevant annotation for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I can use:

```kotlin
@DisabledIfSystemProperty(named = "os.arch", matches = ".*aarch64.*")
```